# relevel in a within environment does not seem to work

Tags: r

I have a data.frame and I would like to relevel one of the factor levels to put it first. However, using a `within` environment does not seem to work. (I am a beginner, so pardon me if it is easy.)

My data frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("Yes","No"),20,replace=TRUE),ncol=1))
levels(df$V1)
[1] "No"  "Yes"
```

Now doing the reordering of factor levels using `relevel`:

```
df <- within(df, relevel(V1, ref="Yes"))
levels(df$V1)
[1] "No"  "Yes"
```

In other words, it does not seem that `relevel` worked. It must be because I use the `within()` environment badly because if I do it "directly" it works:

```
df$V1 <- relevel(df$V1, ref="Yes")
> levels(df$V1)
[1] "Yes" "No"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need

```
df <- within(df, V1 <- relevel(V1, ref="Yes"))
```

because `relevel` returns the relevelled value of the factor but doesn't assign it to a variable.  You're *evaluating* the expression within `df`, but not assigning it to anything. I would probably use

```
df <- transform(df, V1 = relevel(V1, ref="Yes"))
```

instead, but that's a stylistic preference (see also the `plyr`/`dplyr` functions `mutate`, `transmute` ...)

If (as asked in the comments) you have a vector of names (i.e. a character vector), then you can't really use the *non-standard evaluation* paradigm shared by `transform`, `with`, `within`, `subset` (`dplyr` ...) but more or less have to do things the old-fashioned way, e.g.

```
df[vars.to.relevel] <- lapply(df[vars.to.relevel],relevel,ref="Yes")
```

Comment: Thank you. Any pointers to guide my choice about whether to use `transform` or `within`?

Comment: I have a related question. Not sure if I should create another question, but how could I do the same if I have the names of variables I want to relevel as a string vector? eg. `vars.to.relevel <- c("V1", "V2")`

Comment: the old-fashioned way: `df[vars.to.relevel] <- lapply(df[vars.to.relevel],relevel,ref="Yes")` (or use a `for` loop, or use `mapply` or a `for` loop if you have different releveling values for different variables)